# R unable to read factor variables from xlsx

Tags: r

I tried importing an Excel sheet(.xlsx) to R using read.excel. After import the summary command did not yield the right results for factor variables as it did for continuous variables.
Below is the snapshot of the command & the result. Please help.
[Command & results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBwft.png)

[Data snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9ADW.png)

Comment: Instead of screenshots, it would be wiser (and more appropriate) to add inline code

Comment: first, it would have been nice to know the package you're working with. Assuming that it's the `readxl` package which is part of the tidyverse, I am almost entirely sure that they dropped support for reading in factors so that text variables are always imported as character vectors and never as factors (as you're used to from read.csv). I didn't find a source for this (can anyone give one?) but the absence of a `stringsAsFactors` argument and the fact that it's supposed to align with the `readr` package which works the same (no factors) are strong hints imo.

Comment: Sure amonk thanks for the feedback. @freip You rightly said that read.excel doesn't convert strings as factors. I tried converting that excel to csv & it worked completely fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `read_excel` doesn't convert strings as factors. You should manually convert the columns to factors with `custdata$sex <- as.factor(custdata)` and so on.

You can also use the {gdata} or {XLConnect} packages.

Colin